# Linking C library in rust build script

Tags: rust, rust-bindgen

I am trying to learn how to use bindgen. I am following the documentation(https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/tutorial-3.html) and I have the following code to link to a C library:

```
extern crate bindgen;

use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
  println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=vulkan-1");
  println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=vulkan/vulkan.h");

  let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default().header("vulkan/vulkan.h").parse_callbacks(Box::new(bindgen::CargoCallbacks)).generate().expect("Unable to generate bindings");

  let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
  bindings.write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs")).expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

But when I run `cargo build`, I get `note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'vulkan-1.lib'`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @kmdreko Sorry, I edited now

Comment: Does *vulkan-1.lib* exist and is it in a location that's known to the linker?

Comment: By default, the substring `lib` is expected for linked libraries.  Is it possible to rename `vulkan-1` to `libvulkan-1`? Leave as is the `"cargo:rustc-link-lib=vulkan-1"`.